# bash subsetting based on row and column names

Tags: bash, unix

I have a big matrix 1.5M  rows by 150,000 columns. I want subset this big matrix based on a given row and column names. Here is an example of big matrix

```
           c1 c2 c3 c4 
row1       11 12 13 14 

row2       21 22 23 24

row3       31 32 33 34

row4       41 42 43 44

row5       51 52 53 54
```

I want select column c1  and c3 and the file name  that contains these selected columns is called scol. The file name that contains selected rows called srow  and contains row2 row4 row5

The output  looks like as follows

```
     c1  c3 

row2 21  23 

row4 41  43 

row5 51  53
```

Any help?

Comment: This might help: [How to print certain columns by name?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25138/74329)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that *your field separator is **space***.

```
function find_row { grep -P $2 $1; }

function find_column { head -n1 $1 | sed 's/ \+/\n/g' | grep -n $2 | grep -oP '^[0-9]+'; }

function get_column_string { while read line; do find_column $1 $line; done<$2 | sed 's/^/printf " " $/g;s/$/;/g' | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/$/print ""/g; s/^/printf $1;/g'; }

function get_row_string { sed 's/^/^/g;s/$/|/g;' $1 | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/|$//g'; }

function get_subset { grep -P "$(get_row_string $2)" $1 | awk '{'"$(get_column_string $1 $3)"'}'; }
```

after adding these functions.

you can run this:

```
get_subset mainfile.txt srow scol
```

this will output:

```
rows c1 c3
row2 21 23
row4 41 43
row5 51 53
```

assuming that the contents are as follows:

mainfile.txt:

> rows       c1 c2 c3 c4
>
> row1       11 12 13 14
>
> row2       21 22 23 24
>
> row3       31 32 33 34
>
> row4       41 42 43 44
>
> row5       51 52 53 54

scol:

> c1 
>   c3

srow:

> rows 
>   row2 
>   row4 
>   row5